# How to select multiple radios inside p:selectOneRadio

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'd like to display a web page that shows the results of a test containing numerous `multiple choice` type questions. I have the list of options, the candidate's answer and the correct answer to the questions.

For each question I'd like to display a set of disabled radio buttons where you see the correct answer and the candidate's answer. The problem is that when the two differs I have to display two checked radio buttons (background color would indicate the correct one) and it seems to me that primefaces `selectOneRadio` or the `h:selectOneRadio` component don't provide a standard way to do that.

Could you suggest something? Should I try to set it somehow from javascript, or is there a way to do this with standard components based on information acquired from the backing JSF bean?

Comment: Maybe you can change the style of the good answer instead of checking its radio.

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way with radio buttons. Reconsider this from a UI perspective. Maybe you should be putting a tick image for the correct answer, and a cross image indicating the wrong answer the candidate selected. http://jsbin.com/janexahu/1/